# How to get mean of two times in angular4?

Tags: angular

I  mean, for example if I set a start time as 1:00PM and an end time as 7:00 PM, I need break time to get displayed as default value which is 3:00PM.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a function to calculate average from time array :

```
// function will determine average time given a set of 
// times in a 24 hr. period, i.e. 12am - 12pm
// it does NOT work for a 24 hr. period from 12pm - 12am
let times = ['01:00:00 PM', '07:00:00 PM'];

// function accepts an array of times as the argument
// requires time to be structured as above
public getAverageTime(times) {
    let count = times.length
    let timesInSeconds = [];
    // loop through times
    for (let i =0; i < count; i++) {
        // parse
        let pieces = times[i].split(':');
        let ampm = pieces[2].split(' ');
        let hrs = Number(pieces[0]);
        let mins = Number(pieces[1]);
        let secs = Number(ampm[0]);
        let ampm = ampm[1];
        // convert to 24 hr format (military time)
        if (ampm == 'PM') hrs = hrs + 12;   
        // find value in seconds of time
        var totalSecs = hrs * 60 * 60;
        totalSecs += mins * 60;
        totalSecs += secs;
        // add to array
        timesInSeconds[i] = totalSecs;
    }
    // find average timesInSeconds
    let total = 0;
    console.log(timesInSeconds);
    for (var j =0; j < count; j++) {
        total = total + Number(timesInSeconds[j]);
    }
    let avg = Math.round(total / count);
    console.log('avg secs: '+avg);
    // turn seconds back into a time
    let avgMins = Math.floor(avg/60);
    let avgSecs = avg - (60 * avgMins);
    let avgHrs = Math.floor(avgMins/60);
    console.log('hours: '+avgHrs);
    avgMins = avgMins - (60 * avgHrs);
    // convert back to 12 hr. format
    let avgAmpm = 'AM';
    if (avgHrs > 12) {
        avgAmpm = 'PM';
        avgHrs = avgHrs - 12;
    }
    // add leading zeros for seconds, minutes
    avgSecs = ('0' + avgSecs).slice(-2);
    avgMins = ('0' + avgMins).slice(-2);
    // your answer
    return avgHrs+':'+avgMins+':'+avgSecs+' '+avgAmpm;
}
```

Call this function to execute

```
console.log(getAverageTime(times));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help (It could be optimized, but it is worth a shot):

```
 function middleDate(a:Date,b:Date){
      let smaller = a > b? b : a;
      let bigger = a > b? a : b;
      let c = new Date(smaller); // get the smaller date
      let middle = (bigger - smaller)/2;
      c.setTime(c.getTime() + middle);

      return c;
    }
```